# How do I format a date and also pad it with spaces?

Tags: python, formatting, f-string

Formatting appears to work differently if the object you're formatting is a date.

```
today = "aaa"
print(f'{today:>10}')
```

returns

```
       aaa
```

i.e. it has the padding.

If I now do this:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
print(f'{today:>10}')
```

then the response is

```
>10
```

Which is obviously not what I want. I've tried various other combinations where I put in the date format as well, but all it does is draw the date out and then also add in '>10' also.

How do I format a date with padding?

Comment: use https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime ? Edited the link sorry wrong one previously

Comment: @AndrewRyan i want to do it using f strings though. I just tried that function though, how do you pad and align the date within the string?

Comment: first use `strftime` to format time and later you can use f-string to pad it.

Comment: `>10` works only with strings - so you may need `str()` in your `f-string` - `f'{str(today):>10}'`

Comment: `today` is `date`/`datetime` object and it can use only value from `strftime` - `f'{today:Today is %Y:%m:%d}'` - similar to `today.strftime('Today is %Y:%m:%d')` - so it treats `>10` as normal text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's scheme for formatting via f-strings (and the `.format` method of strings) allows the inserted data to override how the format specification works, using the `__format__` magic method:

```
>>> class Example:
...     def __format__(self, template):
...         return f'{template} formatting of {self.__class__.__name__} instance'
... 
>>> f'{Example():test}'
'test formatting of Example instance'
```

`datetime.date` does this, so that `time.strftime` is used to do the formatting (after some manipulation, e.g. inserting a proxy time for dates and vice-versa):

```
>>> help(today.__format__)
Help on built-in function __format__:

__format__(...) method of datetime.date instance
    Formats self with strftime.
```

This means that codes like `%Y` etc. can be used, but field width specifiers (like `>10`) are *not* supported. The format string `>10` doesn't contain any placeholders for any components of the date (or time), so you just get a literal `>10` back.

Fortunately, it is trivial to work around this. Simply coerce the date to string, and pad the string:

```
>>> f'{str(today):>20}'
'          2022-06-13'
```

Or better yet, use the built-in syntax for such coercion:

```
>>> f'{today!s:>20}' # !s for str(), !r for repr()
'          2022-06-13'
```

If you want to use the strftime formatting as well, do the formatting in two steps:

```
>>> formatted = f'{today:%B %d, %Y}'
>>> f'{formatted:>20}'
'       June 13, 2022'
```

Note that it does **not** work to nest format specifiers:

```
>>> # the {{ is interpreted as an escaped literal {
>>> f'{{today:%B %d, %Y}:>20}' 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: f-string: single '}' is not allowed
>>> # the inner {} looks like a dict, but %B isn't an identifier
>>> f'{ {today:%B %d, %Y}:>20}'
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    ( {today:%B %d, %Y})
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, f-strings themselves can be nested (this is obviously not very elegant and will not scale well):

```
>>> # instead of trying to format the result from another placeholder,
>>> # we reformat an entire separately-formatted string:
>>> f'{f"{today:%B %d, %Y}":>20}'
'       June 13, 2022'
```

Comment: Note that it's possible to nest f-strings: `f'{f"{today:%B %d, %Y}":>20}'`

Comment: I did think of that afterward; I'll edit it in just for completeness. Also credit to @wim for reminding me about `!s` - a tool I'd forgotten about because it didn't ever seem necessary for anything before.

Comment: Thanks. exactly what i was looking for with the explanation of why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
today = date.today()

formatted_today = datetime.strftime(today, "%d %B, %Y")
print(f'{str(formatted_today):>10}')
```

Output:

```
2022-06-13
```

Comment: Ah yes. I did mean that forgot to change it.

Comment: now I can delete my previous comment.